# Wordpress: How to count post in a category. Help needed with the second function to count multiple categories

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function

This function can count the number of posts in a category.

```
//working code
add_shortcode( 'cat_count2', 'cat_count2' );
function cat_count2( $atts ) {

$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
  'category' => null,
  'type' => null
), $atts );

$term = get_term_by( 'slug', $atts['category'], 'category');
$tpt = $atts['type'];


return ( isset( $term->count ) ) ? $term->count : 0;
}
```

Festivals ([cat_count2 category="en-festivals"])

---

I need help with a function that can count and add the number of posts in multiple categories. Here is the start of a function. Any help writing something is greatly appreciated.

```
add_shortcode( 'my_post_count', 'my_post_count_func' );
function my_post_count_func($tax, $cat1, $cat2) {
    $yay = array(
        'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $tax,
                'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms' => array( $cat1 ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $tax,
                'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
                'terms' => array( $cat2 ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
        )
    
    );

    return ( isset( $yay->count ) ) ? $yay->count : 0;

}
```

January ([my_post_count categories="en-events,en-january"])

Comment: In the first example, you are properly using shortcode_atts, in the second example, you're not properly passing the shortcode parameters ($atts) to the shortcode.

Comment: How can I do that? Should I just swap "function my_post_count_func($tax, $cat1, $cat2)" with "function my_post_count_func($yay)" and then do something else? Sorry I'm not sure what to do as I usually just copy and paste chunks of working code together to make stuff work. This time I'm just trying to add the number of posts in multiple categories together. That way people can see how many posts there will be on the next page before clicking a link.